# Why this api shows error message "Unknown fields: gender"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using a graph api for facebook app. I am using this api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<friendlist_id>/members?fields=id,name,gender&access_token=<access_token>
```

But it shows me error,

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: gender.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

When I remove "gender" from the api, it works properly. So, why this api shows me this error. How to get gender of a user in this api?

Answer (score 2):

Because according to the [Friend List documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) the `members` connection is `An array of objects containing friend id and name fields.` - those are the only two fields in 
the structure - you'll need to fetch any other data you need about those IDs in another call

(Though most apps would probably already have the result of `/me/friends` cached so this should be pretty fast)

Comment: But if i use `fields=id,name,picture` then it will show me url of picture also.

Comment: hmm, interesting, i didn't realise that would work - do other non-gender fields work too?

Comment: `fields=username,link` works but `languages,first_name,middle_name` are showing error.

Comment: What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: No idea, i don't recommend relying on undocumented behaviour like that though - you could just request all friends' data and compare to the IDs from the friends list?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to pull the gender in one go as [Igy](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12864243/321505) said, so a way to do it in FQL would be

`SELECT uid, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid, flid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid = <friendlist_id>)`